# FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener not called in Fragment class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My navigation drawer contained in MainActivity navigates to several Fragments. In the onCreate method of these Fragment classes, am trying to `onAuthStateChanged` to get the current user:

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null ) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in" + user.getUid());

            } else { //user is not logged in

                Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");

            }

        }
    };
   }
```

but `onAuthStateChanged` is never called.
Similar code in `MainActivity` works just fine. I have tried calling this code in the `onCreateView()` and `onResume()` methods of the Fragment but nothing happens.
To solve this and get the current user, I created a method in the MainActivity:

```
 public FirebaseUser getFirebaseUser() {
    return user;
 }
```

and then called the method in the Fragment class by doing:

```
FirebaseUser user = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getFirebaseUser();

if (user != null ) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in" + user.getUid());

        } else { //user is not logged in

            Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");

        }
```

and everything works just fine. **My question is**, why can't I call

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
      ...
```

from my Fragment classes?

Comment: Did try calling it from fragment's `onViewCreated`?

Comment: It may also be because there is no local instance of your FirebaseAuth object.

Comment: There IS a local instance.That's why getting the user from the container activity works

Comment: But where do you add this listener to this object? `mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);`
 I don't see it in the code. You create it but never add this so it can't be triggered.

Comment: I don't get it.What object?

Comment: The one that you get like this `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();` in your activity. You have to add this listener to it. So you can pass it to your fragment via setter or call `getActivity` and access it as a field.

Comment: this has already been done in `onStart` of MainActivity `firebaseAuthenticator.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);`

Comment: You are adding a different listener to the `mAuth`. You have to add the one that you created in the fragment. Debug it and check the references.

Comment: Solved it @ArnisShaykh. I wasn't adding the listener to the FirebaseAuth object in the callback methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @ArnisShaykh, I discovered I wasn't calling:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener); // firebaseAuth is of class FirebaseAuth
}
```

In the Fragment class.

remember to also add:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser name = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (name != null) {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Subscriber.class));
            }
        }
    };
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
```