# write from Firebase DB to TextView in Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, textview, android-fragmentactivity

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

View myVeiw;
private TextView PUsername_tv, PForename_tv, PSurname_tv;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);//attach AuthStateListner(authListner)
}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myVeiw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_page, container, false);


    PUsername_tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvPUsername);
    PForename_tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvPForename);
    PSurname_tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvPSurname);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
                mDatabase.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    PUsername_tv.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue()));
                    PForename_tv.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("forename").getValue()));
                    PSurname_tv.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("surname").getValue()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        }
    };



    return myVeiw;
}
```

}

I am trying to get the data of the User Logged in to display inside the fragment called Profile( I used a navigation drawer in android studio) I have done this before but only to an Activity not a fragment hence why I need help :D

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: what exactly is not working, is the setText not working?

Comment: You are creating an auth listener object, but you never actually attach the listener, so its code is never executed.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41562916/firebaseauth-authstatelistener-not-called-in-fragment-class.

Comment: Thank you I saw that when i created the OnStart method I attached the listener the problem is that when i try to click on profile fragment the app just shuts down. Ive checked the firebase db and rules no grammar errors so any ideas? also I also tried the onStop method directly below onStart and still the same crashing of app when profile fragment selected.

Comment: I now believe it is no longer to do with attaching the listener. after editing out code until the profile fragment displays. the error lies within         PUsername_tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvPUsername);
      PForename_tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvPForename);
        PSurname_tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvPSurname);                                         Would it be best to put this inside a method and call it into onData change?